# Using Kotlin coroutines to implement a handshake procedure involving a state machine

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm new to Kotlin, and need to implement code that performs a handshake procedure. This means that there's input & output data and a state machine. Example:

```
class Handshake {
    fun readData(data: List<Byte>): Outcome {
        if (currentState == State.STATE_1) {
            if (inspectState1Data(data) == Result.INVALID) {
                return Outcome.NEED_MORE_DATA // 
            } else {
                currentState = State.STATE_2
                return Outcome.CALL_AGAIN
            }
        } else if (currentState == State.STATE_2) {
            when (inspectState2Data(data)) {
                Result.REQUIRES_EXTRA_INFO -> return Outcome.PROVIDE_EXTRA_INFO
                Result.INVALID -> return Outcome.FAILURE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This `readData()` function would have to be repeatedly called. If `Outcome.CALL_AGAIN` is returned, it just is called again. If `Outcome.PROVIDE_EXTRA_INFO` is returned, extra information has to be passed to the Handshake class first somehow etc.

In this example, the function is short and easy to read, however once more states get involved, and the states get more complex, this code can quickly become messy.

I'd like to change that into something like:

```
suspend fun processHandshake(): Boolean {
    // State 1

    while (true) {
        // Loop until we get valid data
        val data: List<Byte> = suspendUntilResumedWithData() // How would this look like in Kotlin?
        if (inspectState1Data(data) != Result.INVALID)
            break
    }

    // State 2

    while (true) {
        // Loop until we are done. If during the process we
        // require extra info, request one. In this state,
        // however, receiving invalid data is not recoverable,
        // we need to exit with failure instead.
        val data: List<Byte> = suspendUntilResumedWithData()
        when (inspectState2Data(data)) {
            Result.REQUIRES_EXTRA_INFO -> {
                val extraInfo: ExtraInfo = suspendUntilResumedWithExtraInfo()
                processExtraInfo(extraInfo)
            }
            Result.INVALID -> return false // Return false to indicate failure
        }
    }

    return true // Success - return true
}
```

To me, the second form is much more readable, and of course works well with the Kotlin coroutines infrastructure, particularly with details like job cancellations etc. This code also has a much more sequential look compared to the other one.

However, I have no clear picture of how `suspendUntilResumedWithData()` and `suspendUntilResumedWithExtraInfo()` would look like. I do know of Continuation objects, but am not sure how to properly use them here. Any suggestions?

Comment: So state 2 looping starts after 1 is completed right, or you want parallel decomposition and select whichever comes first?

Comment: Right. State 1 comes first, followed by state 2.

Comment: I think you need channels instead of loops, because continuation can only be resumed once, and are used for purpose of wrapping async calls, you should not be storing continuation outside.

Comment: I was considering channels before, but wasn't sure if these are the right approach, also because I might have to perform more operations than just feeding in more data. See in the example above the part with "extrainfo". So, I was also looking at implementing something like in the example [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/coroutines.md#restricted-suspension). See how `return suspendCoroutine { cont -> nextStep = cont }` stores a continuation, and how after each step, a new continuation is generated. But you are recommending against this? What's the reason?

Comment: Continuation is not generated, suspendCoroutine acquires the current continuation (of current coroutine block). A contination is resumed then the same contination is acquired again in there. You can decompile to java to get a better image. A continuation is created along creation of coroutine like from launch or async block.

Comment: You should not use high level api with suspendCoroutine otherwise unexpected things might happen, https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/misleading-coroutine-behavior/2513/6 use of suspend coroutine is just for wrapping resume of a coroutine inside of suspendCoroutine block (which exposes continuation, ideally should not be exposed).

Comment: Okay. So, in other words, Continuation is a class that operates on a lower level and should only be used in similarly low level code, right?

And aside from that, given that I need to pass not only data, but also extra info, and also need to inform callers / senders what I now need (or whether I need any data or extra info etc. at all), how would you implement this? By writing an Enum element that contains all possible types of input/output information? In this example, an Enum that contains both the data bytearray and the extrainfo, and passing that enum through a channel?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214811/discussion-between-dv-and-animesh-sahu).